# Add central locking and electric windows to Land Rover Defender (1999)?

Tags: electrical, aftermarket-upgrade

Is it possible to change the manual locking system into central locking system for all three doors for this model of 1999?

Also, can the manual window  opening closing system be changed into an electric system?

Can this be done by a handy man or is a garage needed?

Comment: Are you asking for shopping advice?  You can buy kits for this almost anywhere.

Comment: Why not post a link @Chenmunka?

Comment: Thanks Chenmunka & Erik, I am looking for a garage handy man who can deliver what is necessary and install it!

Comment: I think it might be difficult to find an exact system designed for your particular vehicle.  You probably end up with generic locking mechanism that will require a bit of customization (bending of rods, use of washers or shims, drilling out small plastic holes) in order to get it to function properly.

Comment: Hi Ducatikiller,  Thanks your input. You are probaly right, i just spoken to a defender "specilist",who figured he could do it. i just have to wait and see now.

Comment: Hi, having had a land rover (SIII swb) which I upgraded to V8 and range-rover gearbox, the land rover is meccano for adults! Best place to source bits will be a scrap yard or some of the specialist land rover breakers especially in UK.